# Responsive website not working in mobile

Tags: responsive-design, web

I have designed a responsive website. Everything works fine when I check by resizing browser window. But when I see through mobile view its not responsive.

My site:
[www.ensteps.com](http://www.ensteps.com).

**Mobile View:**
[image]

It's not responsive.

**Window Resizing view:**

[image: Window resizing]

It is responsive.

Please help me to recover this issue. Dont know how to check that responsive...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` to your `<head>` tag.